# In-Proc sessions in Azure hosted web app getting cleared if website is idle for more than 35 min.

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

WebApp is set to always on. Single instance is used no scaling or load balancing. Session timeout set to 60 min. 
Still session is getting cleared.

Comment: That's too long. Default IIS idle timeout to shutdown apppools is 20 minutes as far as I remember. So should be disappearing faster.

Comment: Default timeout has been modified to 60 min

Comment: Azure restarts the app pool, and that's something resetting it, you may would like to move away from in-proc session states, when you don't really have control over the IIS in the case of Azure Web app to not let that happen. what tier have you selected for you webapp

Comment: We are using standard tier. We will use Redis Cache session provider but just curious to know why session is getting cleared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. It was because session was stored in InMemory Cache and CompactOnMemoryPressure flag was true which was clearing 10% of memory under pressure.

Comment: This should be updated to the question and should not be posted as an answer as this doesn't actually provide any valuable answer.